# php: move the sitemap.xml into folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

There is a website having the multi-language functionality archieved by the `.htaccess` file.

I have generated the `sitemap.xml` file and I can access it with `sitename.com/sitemap.xml`

Having a little experience in php, I would ask how can I 'move' the .xml file into a place so that I can access it via `sitename.com/ro/sitemap.xml` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just keep `sitemap.xml` in root folder and add this rule in `DocumentRoot` .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^ro/(sitemap\.xml)$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

Now you can use this URL as `http://sitename.com/ro/sitemap.xml`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69581/discussion-between-anubhava-and-florin-m).